# Wordpress - Timeline Vertical (Collapse)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am looking to create a timeline vertical on Wordpress. Easy enough. However, I want it set up so that when the icon is clicked, the text underneath is revealed. I am not sure if this is going to take adding certain HTML tags to each and every single content box.

I attempted looking through the design settings. I expected to find a "collapse" or "expand" setting, but I did not see anything that alludes to that.

Comment: The block editor does not have a built-in **accordion** block, but there are several third-party accordion blocks available.